# How to pass url parameters to JSF/xHTML?

Tags: jsf, url, facelets, parameters

I know this has been asked multiple times but mine is a slightly diff question.

I have a JSF page which queries a database and throws results, before i move to JSF, i used to do this in JSP and it was working fine.

When i was using JSP below is the link format i used to use

```
http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.jsp?SearchString=Name&Category=Contact&Submit=Submit
```

My index.jsp used to capture the values using param.SearchString & param.Category, and 'Submit' used to activate the 'submit' button for the search.

How do i do the same for xHTML/JSF ?

Here is what i tried ...

```
http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.xhtml?search=#{some search string}
```

In my index.xhtml

```
    <td>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="search" value="#{databaseSearch.searchstring}" />
    </f:metadata>
  <p:inputText id="searchstring" size="20" maxlength="20"  value="#{databaseSearch.searchstring}"/> <p:commandButton id="submit" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Search Database" update="panel" actionListener="#{databaseSearch.customerList}" />
    </td>
```

in my databaseSearch.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "databaseSearch")
@SessionScoped

public class databaseSearch implements Serializable {

    public String searchstring;
  //getter and setter for searchstring
}
```

Also, i would need it 'Submit' the form .... I am new to this, so please excuse me if this was already discussed before ...

Also if i specific index.html , my jsf components would not load, just a blank page. like if i go

```
http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/
```

my primefaces components load fine, but if i do

```
 http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.xhtml
```

it does not, so now i am wondering how to pass the parameters :(

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: *if i do `http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.xhtml` it does not* Looks like a problem in your Faces Servlet URL mapping. Please post that part of the configuration from the web.xml file to get further help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can <f:metadata> and <f:viewParam> be used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Will do ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could 'submit' your form adding `<f:event type="preRenderView">` inside the `<f:metadata>` tag.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="search" value="#{databaseSearch.searchstring}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{databaseSearch.doSearch}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This way, you could implement how your bean will search for this specific query string

```
public void doSearch(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if(!searchString.isEmpty()) {
        // Do your search here 
    }
}
```

Comment: @TelsonAlva edit your question and add the related stacktrace.

Comment: I got it .... i had two parameters and i was only passing one :) .. rookie mistake ... this worked like a charm !

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for

Answer (score 2):

Your Faces Servlet maps to anything that's hold in the *faces* virtual folder:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So `http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.xhtml` URL won't be parsed through Faces Servlet. You must use `http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/faces/index.xhtml`, note the use of `faces/` before your `index.xhtml` file, also note that your `<welcome-file>` also points to `faces/index.xhtml`.

The downside of this URL pattern is that Faces Servlet would also process non-facelets resources like JavaScript files (*.js), Style files (*.css), images (*.png, *.jpg) and others. A better Faces Servlet mapping would be:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this way, Faces Servlet will process xhtml pages **only** and you won't need the *faces* virtual folder anymore. With this change, now you can access to `http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase/index.xhtml` with no problems.

Comment: slight problem ... when i include index.xhtml it works fine now ... but i would also like to open the same page by just entering http://localhost:8080/blmdatabase  is that possible ?

Comment: @TelsonAlva Change your `<welcome-file>` accordingly to not use `faces` but directly `index.xhtml`.

Comment: You are awsome ! i am having issues with sorting a dynamicDatable ... could you help me with that ? i could create another question

Comment: @TelsonAlva that should be in a new question.

Comment: done -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019513/primefaces-datatable-sorting-does-not-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

you could use a method in the class dataBaseSearch:

```
if(searchString != null){
//execute a query in database
// return result to a variable(resultSet or list)
}
```

and use getter and setter to get the the resultSet or List
and render the result in a datatable.